# How to asynchronously update Mysql row count?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to display the total no. of row count asynchronously for every 5 second. I've created a page to get the row count. But, wanna update the count without reloading the page.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pswd", "db_pswd");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM tweets;
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $rowcount;
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Don't know how to proceed to next. Need some help to achieve this!

Comment: AJAX & Timer will help you....

Comment: There is no need to fetch all the table contents in order to count the rows in it. Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweets` and it will return one row in result which has the *count* of rows in the table.

Comment: @user1844933 : Some code will be more helpful

Comment: @poncha : Sure, i will modify the code. Any code to update the `$rowcount` for every 5 sec without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN HTML page:

```
    Count:

<div id="rowcount"></div>

setInterval(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
    url:'yourPHP,
    success:function(data){
    $('#rowcount').html(data); 
}, 5000);
```

in PHP :

```
$sql="SELECT count(id) FROM tweets";
```

this will return the number you needed,print it

Comment: Hi, do i  need to create another Html or php page to enter with code?

Comment: No,the DIV and the JS code in your display html page, the $sql in your PHP file

where yourPHP is your PHP file

Comment: If you don't mind, can you pl give me the full code of html page please? i'm completely new to this. pl!

Comment: <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
Count:   <div id="rowcount"></div>
<script>
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'test2.php',
            success:function(data){
                $('#rowcount').html(data); 
            }
        })
    }, 5000);

</script>


Download :jquery.min.js

test2.php  is your php file where you can write :

$sql="SELECT count(id) as current_count FROM tweets";

and fetch current_count and echo it, so it will be backed to your page

Comment: This is my `HTML` file but it doesn't refresh automatically after every 5 second.[Code](http://s12.postimg.org/ljgwnzkil/Capturefds.jpg)

Comment: what in your test2.php?

Comment: This are my Html & Php [code](http://s2.postimg.org/ce050neuh/stckup.jpg). Where i'm making mistake?

Comment: <?
echo time();
?>


I write the above in test2.php , and it runs good

Comment: Tried that too. Only if i refresh it changes :(

Answer (score 0):

use ajax

```
setTimeout(function(){$.ajax({
url:'GiveURL', /* such as index.php*/
method:'get',
dataType:'text or html',
success:function(data){
    $('#GiveId').html(data); /* give id of your div or textbox*/
}
});
},5*1000);
```

Comment: Do i need to create any php page or to insert directly in `index.php`?

Comment: no you give name of php file such index.php or mysqlRow.php

Comment: i mean do i want to insert the above code in `index.php` itself??

Comment: Thanks @Man Programmer. Also i want to automaically change for every 5 sec. How to set?

Comment: This are my Html & Php [code](http://s2.postimg.org/ce050neuh/stckup.jpg). Where i'm making mistake?